# Test for null hypothesis: the rank of each variable is uniformly distributed

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, ranking, discrete-distributions

Assume the following situation:

I have $N$ samples of $k$ continuos variables, $$x_n = (x^n_1,...,x^n_k).$$

I do not trust whether I can combine the continuos variables across samples, but I want to use their ranks at least.

As an example for clarity, consider the situation where each $x^n_i$ corresponds to the score that student $i$ in a class obtains on the $n$-th maths-test of a year. These tests are all written by different teachers with different methods, so the scores might come from different distributions, and we decide against summing them up. However, we could assume that the rank of the students in every tests always are samples of the true but unknown class/population distribution of the ranks.

Thus, I order the values from lowest to highest, to obtain $N$ samples of ranks $$r^n = (r^n_1,...,r^n_k)$$
which are supposed to be i.i.d. samples from $$R = (R_1,...,R_k).$$

Now I thought about computing the average, normalized rank, $$\overline{r}_i=\frac{1}{N} \sum_n \frac{r_i^n}{k}$$

If I could assume that the $R_i$ are independent, uniform $R_i \sim Uniform(\{1,...,k\})$, then I could assess the p-value of the $\overline{r}_i$ by refering to the distribution of the sum of $N$ i.i.d. uniform discrete variables, whatever that may be. But the assumption of independence does not hold in the beginning, since every rank can only be given once.

So, how do I test for every $\overline{r}_i$ if it is bigger than expected under the nullhypothesis? Or any other ideas how to tackle my question?

Comment: Are you re-inventing the Quade test or the Kruskal-Wallis test? www.jstor.org/stable/2286991

Comment: I definitely do not want to reinvent anything, I just need someone to point out an appropiate test for me :D. From my reading, the kruskal-wallis-test would test whether the $N$ samples are all from the same population. I rather assume that all of them come from the same distribution, but want to check whether that is the uniform distribution. Even more I am interested in which of the $\overline{r_i}$ are bigger than what one would see under uniform distribution. E.g., like a one-sample t-test, but $N$ is rather small + I do not know how to deal with the dependence.